# What transformers to declare when developing a library using Reflectable?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have a library that makes use of dart:mirrors and I want to try to remove the mirrors dependency by using reflectable.

However, all example code I find for using reflectable is targeted for end-user projects and include transformers with entry points for `web/main.dart`. A library has no main file.

What transformers should I declare? Should I require users of the library to add transformers to their pubspec file?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you ask about. See my answer and add a comment if I missed the point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the users of you package need to add a transformer to the `transformers` section in `pubspec.yaml`.
Transformers are only allowed to process resources in the current package (where it is listed in the pubspec.yaml).
You also need to add it to the `pubspec.yaml` of your library package if the transformer needs to process resources in your package when the application is built, but you don't need to add and entry point.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/code_transformers/issues/17

Comment: How do I "add it to the pubspec.yaml of your library package if the transformer needs to process resources in your package when the application is built"?

Comment: Just add it as transformer in your `pubspec.yaml` like any other transformer. `transformers: - myTransformer` (with a line break).

Comment: But there is no `myTransformer`. But perhaps you mean adding the reflectable import transformer? I was creating an experimental project, I will further look into it when I get back home.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If you  need any transformer applied to code in your package, you need to add this transformer to your `pubspec.yaml`. This can be the `reflectable` transformer or any other transformer.